# Why "npx prisma db pull" is blocked on Introspecting?

Tags: database, next.js, prisma, supabase

hello I want to add a table in my database (supabase). So I add this in supabase. And when I try to pull my table (from database supabase) with `npx prisma db pull` for uptdate prisma schema the command is blocked.

I try also this and I have the same result : `npx prisma migrate dev`

It’s been a while since I had assigned a command with prisma on this project but otherwise everything works because I can use the database in my project

I don’t know much prisma so I may have forgotten something
Thank you for your help

[prisma stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6g0b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just fired up a new project to verify that this works:

```
npm init
npm install prisma --save-dev
```

Add .env file with database information, e.g.

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres.xxxxyyyyzzzz:passpasspass@aws-0-us-west-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres?schema=public"
```

where postgres.xxxxyyyyzzzz is they user name, and passpasspass is the password

Then run

```
npx prisma init --datasource-provider postgresql
```

And finally:

```
npx prisma db pull
```

Which produces the prisma/schema.prisma file, first few lines:

```
/// This model contains row level security and requires additional setup for migrations. Visit https://pris.ly/d/row-level-security for more info.
model locations {
  location_name    String             @db.VarChar(255)
  street_address   String             @db.VarChar(255)
  city             String             @db.VarChar(100)
  state_province   String             @db.VarChar(100)
  postal_code      String             @db.VarChar(20)
  unit_number      String?            @db.VarChar(20)
  notes            String?
  id               String             @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  service_requests service_requests[]
}
```

Edit:  Then I added a new table Foo, and ran `npx prisma db pull` again, adds the table to the schema

```
/// This model or at least one of its fields has comments in the database, and requires an additional setup for migrations: Read more: https://pris.ly/d/database-comments
/// This model contains row level security and requires additional setup for migrations. Visit https://pris.ly/d/row-level-security for more info.
model foo {
  id         BigInt   @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. I had put the wrong port in .env file for DATABASE_URL. I don’t know why I had port 6543 but now it works thanks !